# Submitting jscolor result to shell_exec command

Tags: php, variables, exec, jscolor

To start with: My web coding skills are nearly to non existent, I just did a bit of HTML ages ago...
And my first steps with php are just made today.

My goal is: Having a color picker and sending the picked value as an argument to an python script.

I managed to use the jscolor picker libary (http://jscolor.com/examples/) and I've been also able to run the python scripts with an (color) argument from php.

My problem is now:

How do I submit the color string (hex-str) to the exec command (LED_color)?

```
<?php
    $LED_color="FFFFFF";

    $LED_color=escapeshellarg($LED_color);

    if (isset($_POST['button']))
    {
        $LED_color = $_REQUEST['hex-str'];
        echo shell_exec("sudo /home/pi/LEDscripts/color-by-arg.py $LED_color");
    }
?>


<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic usage</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="position:absolute; left:280px; top:10px;">
    toString = <span id="hex-str"></span><br />
</div>


<script src="jscolor.js"></script>

Color: <input class="jscolor {closable:true,closeText:'Close me!',onFineChange:'update(this)'}" value="000000">

<script>
function update(picker) {
    document.getElementById('hex-str').innerHTML = picker.toString();
}
</script>

<form method="post">
    <p>
        <button name="button">Submit color</button>
    </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cXRn.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your color picker input needs a `name` attribute to match your PHP code, and also needs to be inside the `<form>` element.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["hex-str"])) {
    $LED_color = escapeshellarg($_POST["hex-str"]);
    echo shell_exec("sudo /home/pi/LEDscripts/color-by-arg.py $LED_color");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic usage</title>
    <script src="jscolor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <p>
            Color:
            <input type="text" name="hex-str" value="000000" class="jscolor" data-jscolor="{closable:true,closeText:'Close me!',onFineChange:'update(this)'}"/>
            toString = <span id="hex-str-display"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit">Submit color</button>
        </p>
    </form>
    <script>
        function update(picker) {
            document.getElementById('hex-str-display').innerHTML = picker.toString();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately it's still not working. The script is always called with the initial value from `LED_color` `FFFFFF`, when the button is clicked. Afterwards the color picker jumps back to it's initial value `000000`

Comment: Maybe one last thing, the color picker jumps back to it's initial value each time the button is pressed. I guess it has something to do, with the page reload. Is there a way of storing the picker value?

Comment: `value="<?=$LED_color?>"` instead of `value="ffffff"`